# IllegalArgumentException - Tomcat start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, illegalargumentexception

Everything was working well, but I clicked on my project in package explorer in Eclipse and exported war file, then my tomcat7 server stopped working. I've got exception:

```
2012-08-24 11:55:19 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
2012-08-24 11:55:19 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Applish' did not find a matching property.
2012-08-24 11:55:20 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
2012-08-24 11:55:20 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
2012-08-24 11:55:20 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1531 ms
2012-08-24 11:55:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
2012-08-24 11:55:20 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: avalon-framework-api,xml-apis,junit,classworlds,log4j,servletapi-Extension-Name
    at java.util.jar.Attributes$Name.<init>(Attributes.java:464)
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.getValue(Attributes.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.getRequiredExtensions(ManifestResource.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.processManifest(ManifestResource.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ManifestResource.<init>(ManifestResource.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

Can anyone figure out what's going on ?

Answer (score 2):

This usually means that one of the jars included in your webapp contains an invalid manifest entry (it contains a comma delimited extensions list instead of a space
delimited list). I can't tell from the stacktrace which jar is causing this. Some people have reported that a similar issue was caused by `jaxen-1.1-beta-11.jar`.