# starting tomcat 6: ZipException - IllegalArgumentException: addRepositoryInternal

Tags: java, maven, tomcat6

I am using Eclipse Indigo with Tomcat 6 with Java 1.5 as compiler, in a maven environment on Win 7 64-bit. My project compiles with no errors, until when I start the server where I get the following stacktrace.

**What I have tried:**

1. Adding `rt.jar` which contains the ZipException class to the Tomcat 6.0 `lib` folder
2. Ading `rt.jar` to the workspace project as an external library via Eclipse's Project Build Path
3. Adding a dependency to include the `rt.jar` in the project's `pom` file
4. Looked at this similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107320/illegalargumentexception-tomcat-start) but with a different exception, and couldn't find a jar file with 0 bytes.
5. Tried restarting eclipse, cleaning the server, cleaning Tomcat's Work Directory
6. Added and remove the app from the server application
7. Created a totally new workspace and added the project (compiled ok), added Tomcat6 server and did items 1-6 to no avail

Please help me SO, you're my only [hope](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIFJLMyUwrg)

**stacktrace**

```
Bootstrap: Class loader creation threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addRepositoryInternal
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.addRepositoryInternal(StandardClassLoader.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.<init>(StandardClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:402)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:203)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:132)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader.addRepositoryInternal(StandardClassLoader.java:944)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you insist in adding `rt.jar` (the Java runtime, I assume) to an application-level classpath?  You should make `rt.jar` a provided dependency and rely on the `rt.jar` supporting Tomcat (and all the applications in it).

Comment: could you give details when you mention that i should `make rt.jar a provided dependency`. Do you mean to create a dependency for it in the project `pom` file?

Comment: @bouncingHippo  Could you answer my questions first?  Why do you insist in adding rt.jar to an application-level classpath?  And an implicit one:  Is rt.jar the Java runtime library?  If you don't know, what is its size?

Comment: the size in my C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_22 is 36.4mb